# How can I grab data from an already parsed non-json API in python containing proxies?

Tags: python, python-2.7, api, selenium

I bought a proxy service which gives me an API that when opened, shows what seems like a big text file of stacked proxies like this, example:

```
39.134.10.2:8080
139.59.2.223:8888
39.134.10.250:8080
61.5.207.102:80
39.134.146.130:8088
60.194.46.119:3128
161.139.222.254:9000
39.134.10.21:8080
148.217.94.54:3128
60.194.46.118:3128
39.134.10.28:8080
39.134.10.250:90
200.255.122.174:8080
219.239.142.253:3128
118.190.210.227:3128
```

I want to make it an updating dictionary in python 2.7. Most of what i've seen is people either webscraping proxies or using json to get them. My API link gets an error:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

I just need to send the ip(s) to a dictionary in Python which then I can make selenium use.

I tried to do this:

```
import urllib2, json
ipadd = urllib.urlop('link to API')
json.load(ipadd)
```

I could always copy-paste the ip(s) to a notepad every 24 hours but that defeats the purpose of the API and I'm sure it's something easy that I don't see. I'm new to network programming. Thank you

Comment: When you visit the API with a browser the ips are in the form you posted ?

Comment: You need something like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) that runs a task every 24 or so hours and put them in a file which you could use in your `selenium` script

Comment: @game0ver yes. you can see that here: http://prntscr.com/k7ooww

Comment: @ThatBird the service deletes any proxies over 24 hours old automatically, so as long as I update my dictionary every 10 minutes I should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
import requests

url = 'your_API_url'
ips = requests.get(url).text
for ip in ips.splitlines():
    # process each ip and port
```

Comment: I knew it was a simple solution! Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem! Also the reason why you got the error is because the data are not in json format. A lot of services usually provide different url API schemes so that you can get the data in different formats.

Comment: the link says PHP. is there anyway to extract php data?

Comment: well thanks for your help! that's an assignment for me to research. :)